# Can intersection of two different maximal ideals of Euclidean ring contain prime element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Can intersection of two different maximal ideals of Euclidean ring contain prime element?

We define $I$ maximal ideal of ring $R$, if there is no such ideal $I’ \neq R$, that $I \subset I’ \subset R$.

Comment: Please clarify if  your definition of Euclidean *ring* requires that the ring is a *domain*.

Comment: We define ring $R$ Euclidean, if it corresponds to the following properties.

Comment: You didn't list any "following properties". The property I asked about is "integral domain", i.e is a Euclidean ring an integral domain *by your definition*?

Comment: We define ring $R$ Euclidean, if it corresponds to the following properties. 1) For all $a, b\in R$ if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$. 2) For each non-zero element we define numeral characteristic — norm $N: R\backslash{0}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}, N(r)\geq 0$. 3) For all $a, b\in R\exists q, r: a=qb+r$ and either $r=0$, or $N(r)<N(b)$. 4) For all $a, b\in R, a\neq 0, b\neq 0$ it is true that $N(ab)\geq max(N(a), N(b))$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime element in the ring.

Then $(p)$ is maximal as if $(p)\subset (m)$, then $m\mid p$ which implies that either $m$ is a unit (in which case $(m) = (1)$) or $(m) = (p)$, either case, we see that $(p)$ is the largest pricipal proper-ideal in the ring.

Now, Euclidean rings are PIDs, so, $(p)$ is maximal.